# How to make clickable Custom MKAnnotationView without the callout view

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I want to create a custom MKAnnotationView like below

[image: Map Annotation will look like this]

After click on Custom MKAnnotationView, want to navigate to detail view.

I have created this custom view, but not able to click on this view.

I have tried with didSelectAnnotationView method  as well, but it didn't work for me.

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
        //here you action
    NSLog(@"didSelectAnnotationView");

}
```

Custom MKAnnotationView add on MapView:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    MKAnnotationView *returnedAnnotationView = nil;
        // handle our custom annotations

    returnedAnnotationView = [CustomAnnotation createViewAnnotationForMapView:self.mapViewList annotation:annotation];
    [returnedAnnotationView setEnabled:YES];
    [returnedAnnotationView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    return returnedAnnotationView;
```

}

```
@implementation CustomAnnotation 

+ (MKAnnotationView *)createViewAnnotationForMapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation  {
    MKAnnotationView *returnedAnnotationView = (CustomAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([CustomAnnotation class])];

    if (returnedAnnotationView == nil) {
        returnedAnnotationView = [[CustomAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([CustomAnnotation class])];
        [returnedAnnotationView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    }
    return returnedAnnotationView;
}

@end
```

what's do wrong me please help!

Comment: Try checking delegate is assigned properly and also confirm annotation view subviews are having user interaction property to be false.

Comment: can  you post code how you are adding callout view o mapview ?

Comment: @HirenPatel : Yes, delegate is properly assigned. I have multiple custom annotations which is only having Image works properly. Only this one not working which is having other details.

Comment: @yashica15, just make sure all subviews in custom annotation view e.g. label and rating view are having userInterctionEnabled to false.

Comment: @CodeChanger: See my edits.

Comment: @HirenPatel: Yes, all subviews have userInterctionEnabled = false;

Comment: Have you added any button on that Custom view ?

Comment: @CodeChanger: No, There is no button there.

Comment: Ok than I also need to check `createViewAnnotationForMapView method ,Can you post this method also ?

Comment: @CodeChanger: See edits.

Comment: Everything looks fine one more thing have you confirm your Custom Class `CustomAnnotationView` with `MKAnnotation` ?

Comment: @CodeChanger: 'CustomAnnotationView' is Custom class of 'MKAnnotationView' and 'CustomAnnotation' is Custom class of 'MKAnnotation'

Comment: Did you set MKAnnotationView image property? Try set image with clear view.